# Python: how to sort random numbers in list

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I am making an program that simulates the roll of a dice 100 times. Now I want to sort the output of the random numbers that are given by the program. How do I have to do that?

```
import random

def roll() :
    print('The computer will now simulate the roll of a dice 100 times')
    list1 = print([random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(100)])

roll()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not *have* a list. The `print()` function returns `None`, not whatever it just printed to your terminal or IDE.

Store the random values, *then* print:

```
list1 = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(100)]
print(list1)
```

Now you can just sort the list:

```
list1 = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(100)]
list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

Comment: When i follow your instructions and run the program, it prints the random numbers, but then it prints 'None' and it doesn't show a sorted list. How do i have to fix this?

Comment: Use `return list1` to return the list from the `roll()` function.

Comment: And don't *print*` the `list1.sort()` call, it returns `None` as it sorts the list *in place*.

Answer (score 2):

The above problem can also be solved using **for loop** as follows -

```
>>> import random

>>> mylist = []

>>> for i in range(100):
        mylist.append(random.randint(1,6))


>>> print(mylist)
```

To sort the list, issue the following commands -

```
>>> sortedlist = []
>>> sortedlist = sorted(mylist)
>>> print(sortedlist)
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the original list:

```
list1.sort()
```

If you need the original list:

```
list2 = sorted(list1)
```

See python.org:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/